# Add custom property with AspNet.Identity.Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

For a MVC5 project I'm working on I need to use a MySQL database and Asp.Net Identity. I'm using the AspNet.Identity.Mysql package from Nuget. It's a database first approach. The defaults are working fine and I can register a user. But now I want to add an extra property to the user model, but I can't figure out why it is not working.

I've added an extra column in the users table "Debnr". In my ApplicationUser I've added a property called Debnr (see code below).

IdentityModels.cs

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{


public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);


    return userIdentity;
}

public string Debnr { get; set; }

}
```

In my AccountController.Register I have:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                user.Debnr = model.Debnr;

                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

In my view and RegisterModel I've added the Debnr property. When I run my code I can see that the Debnr property is populated in the account controller, but somehow it's not writing it to the database.

Comment: Well , you shouldn't touch your db in that case. Just add the property to your Model and migrate with Entity Framework. After that it should work as expected.